# Laptop not Booting into Anything (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have an HP Pavilion dv4t that I bought last year. I recently upgraded to Windows 7.

This problem just started a few hours ago. When the computer starts up and boots into Windows 7, I get a bluescreen which says "UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME".
When I try to insert the HP Recovery Disc the Windows 7 disc, or boot into the recovery partition, none of them load up. (When I insert the Windows 7 disc, it stays stuck at the startup animation; when I insert the HP Recovery disc, it stays at a black screen with just the mouse cursor; when I boot into the recovery partition, the computer just restarts)  So at this point, there is virtually nothing in my knowledge that I can do to fix this problem.

Could there be something wrong with one of the laptop's components such as the hard drive or graphics card? The laptop does get fairly hot when I use it, could this have maybe fried the hard drive?

What kind of solution is there to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you happen to have a live CD of sometype you might try loading that into the laptop and seeing if the computer can actually boot into anything at all. If that works, you might try to get into the BIOS of the laptop and see if anything changed there like the boot order or something to that effect.

With the laptop being only a year or so old, getting a second harddrive is not that expenseive. It's quite possible that the drive did die on you so with a replacement you can always try again. In that same vain, you might see if the machine is still under warranty or if there is some type of recall on the machine.

Hope this helps some, and good luck.

Comment: I called HP, and I am still under warranty, and they're sending me a replacement drive.